# Paypal Checkout currency problem

Tags: paypal, paypal-express

i am facing problem for paypal.
I have enable multi currency option including Taiwan , Singapore , Australian currency etc. 
if i select Singapore dollar as display currency and went for checkout , pay-pal showing USD in checkout page. cosotmer are not able to pay as per display currency
Kindly help me
Note - Base currency is USD , 
Display/allowed currency is as mentioned above.. Kindly guide me what is the problem